# Get a 404 Error when clone, pull mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, clone, apache-config, hgrc

I have a repository in here http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/

I using hgweb.cgi
this is my hgweb.config file

```
[web]
baseurl = 
#allowpull = true
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
allow_archive = bz2 gz zip

[paths]
/ = /home/repos/*
```

I can browse it but I can't clone it. Every time I clone it I have this error

```
hg clone http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello
destination directory: hello
requesting all changes
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

and the access log have that

```
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:33 -0600] "GET /hello?pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&cmd=between HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:34 -0600] "GET /hello?cmd=heads HTTP/1.1" 200 41 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:34 -0600] "GET /hello?cmd=changegroup&roots=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 HTTP/1.1" 404 597 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
```

But I can clone it using uncompressed transfer

```
hg clone --uncompressed http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello
```

But now I don't know how to pull the from the repository, because when I pull from it.
it have the same problem like clone. also for incoming.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
#write base depending on where the base url lives
#RewriteBase /hg
RewriteRule ^$ hgweb.cgi  [L]
# Send requests for files that exist to those files.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Send requests for directories that exist to those directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Send requests to hgweb.cgi, appending the rest of url.
RewriteRule (.*) hgweb.cgi/$1  [QSA,L]
```

I can push revison to the repository but can't pull from it.

Is there anyway to configure this or something to make it work.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Thanks,
Yuan

Comment: @Damiel Read the FAQ (says "software tools commonly used by programmers") and the bazzilion non-programming questions asked about VCS's and IDE's

Comment: What's your .htaccess look like?

Comment: Hi @TheLQ, I have add my .htaccess file on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I have found out the problem.

comment out the following line in /home/my_username/.hgrc

```
#verbose = True
```

more detail [here](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=3558)

Comment: Would be amazing to copy the relevant part of the link to the answer as it is now dead...

Answer (score 1):

This may sound obvious but have you tried uncommenting the `#allowpull = true` line in your `hgweb.config` file?

Comment: Actually allowpull option is true by default.

Comment: Hi @splattne and @TomFluff, the problem is in the /home/my_username/.hgrc file. comment out this line `#verbose = True`. more detail [here](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=3558)

Answer (score 0):

Question: are you running a hgweb.cgi and aliasing it via your web server?

If so http://url/hello might actually be pointing to http://url/hgweb.cgi/hello and that might be the path its looking for.  Typically you have a cgi script serving the mercurial web interface.

Comment: Oh also, if your work or where ever you are is like mine they might have stuff like that blocked for external locations

C:\hello>hg clone http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello
abort: error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively re
fused it

Comment: Yes, I'm using the hgweb.cgi and using the .htaccess to do this

Comment: it is not true because you can use uncompressed transfer to clone it. Also you can push to the repository too.

Answer (score 0):

1. upgrade mercurial to lates version
2. try to replace [paths] section to

   ```
   [collections]
   / = /home/repos

   [web]
   baseurl =
   ```
3. update hgrc for all your repos

   ```
   [web]
   allow_read = YOUR_USER1, YOUR_USER2
   allow_push = YOUR_USER1
   push_ssl = false
   ```

Comment: What is the syntax for [collections] on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you are hosting hgweb in IIS and a pull request exceeds the maximum query string length on the server.  The default of 2048 bytes can be increased by configuring the [system.webServer/security/requestFilters/requestLimits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits) config section.